# Regex for name should start with a letter

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to write a regex for name which starts with a letter and can also have spaces, numbers in the string.

Currently I am using `^(?=.*[a-zA-Z].*)([a-zA-Z0-9' ]{1,50})$`.

But it is accepting the string like "1125151asdgvhavdg". i.e., it is taking numbers at the starting.

My string should look like this

> ads564564545456 fdsf78

Comment: any example of input that you accept?

Comment: it can be like this: a123ajdbhbd

Comment: What do you have `.*` for in your lookahead assertion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As simple as:

```
^([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9' ]{0,49})$
```

You don't need any assertions here

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code:

`^([a-zA-Z\s][a-zA-Z0-9]{1,50})$`

This regex starts with characters and allow spaces and numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can express it succinctly like this:

```
 ^(?i)[a-z][a-z\d ]{0,49})$
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not 100% sure that there will be forever only Ascii letters to be matched, then you should have a look at [Unicode properties](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop), e.g. for letter `\p{L}`.

`\p{L}` any kind of letter from any language.

Or [Unicode scripts](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#script), that collect letters needed for certain languages.

So your regex would look like this:

```
^\p{L}[\p{L}\p{Nd}' ]{0,49}$
```

I replaced also `0-9` by the property `\p{Nd}` (a digit zero through nine in any script except ideographic scripts.)